# how to show applets on smartphone devices

Tags: applet, smartphone

i have created simple applet program and hosted in tomcat server.

it works good in PC's browsers. but when i try to load that page in smart phones (android, iphone ) could not work.

Does the applet supports on smartphones ?

or is there any additional configurations that i need to do ?

Is there any option to install java plugin on smartphones(android , iphone) browsers?

Answer (score 3):

I think now most of smartphone not support applet.
But if you use framework like phonegap then may be you can get exact GUI.
And yes Android has not JVM so android can not run your applet contain class file.
And iphone also not support JAVA. Iphone support only Objective-C.